# How to get a group's start and end index within the RegEx text in Dart?

Tags: regex, dart

e.g. with the following code:

```
final regex = RegExp(r'([0-9]).*([A-Z])');
final text = 'Test 5 with B';
final match = regex.firstMatch(text);
```

Then `match.group(1)` is `'5'`, and `match.group(2)` is `'B'`. However, how do I get each group's start and end index so I can replace them with space or something?

Comment: The `.start()` and `.end()`  methods of `Match` object do not provide any way to get their indices. You need to replace the match directly. So, you want to replace `5` and `B` only *once* or can you replace them globally?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to say replace the first group with "Cat" and replace the second group with "Dog", so ideally if I could get `group(1)`'s start 5 & end 6, and `group(2)`'s start 13 & end 14, then I can do `text.substring(0, 5) + "Cat" + text.substring(6, 13) + "Dog"

Comment: You cannot get the start and end of capture groups. Dart is based on the JavaScript `RegExp` design (because it needs to be compiled to JavaScript), and in JavaScript there is no way to get such indices. Because of that, Dart also doesn't expose those indices, because it wouldn't work if compiled to JavaScript. (It could, the internal implementation makes the start/end index available, but it has to hide that information the same way the browser does it).

Comment: Great to know the reasoning thanks @lrn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Match.start()` and `Match.end()` methods of the `Match` object do not provide any way to get the group indices. You need to replace the first match directly with a pattern where you *capture what you need to keep*:

```dart
final regex = RegExp(r'[0-9](.*)[A-Z]');
final text = 'Test 5 with B';
print(text.replaceFirstMapped(regex, (match) {
   return "Cat${match.group(1)}Dog"; }
));
// => Test Cat with Dog
```

Here,

- `[0-9](.*)[A-Z]` matches a digit, then captures any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, into Group 1 and then `[A-Z]` matches an uppercase ASCII letter
- `replaceFirstMapped` replaces the first match...
- `"Cat${match.group(1)}Dog"` - with `Cat` + Group 1 value + `Dog`.

Comment: Ah that's a smart way to achieve it. Thanks!